# SQL Server XML - setting node names from SQL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I generate node names in a `SELECT FOR XML` statement?

Say I have the table:

```
declare @Products table (ID int, Name varchar(100))
insert into @Products (1, 'Balls')
insert into @Products (2, 'Paper')
insert into @Products (3, 'Beer')
```

I want the following XML output:

```
<Products>
    <Balls @ID=1/>
    <Paper @ID=2/>
    <Beer @ID=3/>
</Products>
```

If not possible, can I use SQL Server XML DML to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can do that with `FOR XML PATH` commands in straight forward way.

So after thinking a lot i came up with following solution which is something awkward but it works:

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE (ID int, Name varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @Products (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'Balls'),
       (2, 'Paper'),
       (3, 'Beer')

SELECT 
    CAST('<' + NAME + ' id="' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR) + '" />' AS XML)
FROM 
    @Products
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Products')
```

Output:

```
<Products>
  <Balls id="1" />
  <Paper id="2" />
  <Beer id="3" />
</Products>
```

AND here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/539f4/2)

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot, especially since this table is small and performance not an issue.

Comment: Missing an @ before id,but that is minor.